# Setting the foreground[text] color of the button in a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml, generic.xaml

I am defining a  button style in Buttons.xaml file. Can you please tell me how to set the foreground property  of the button? I need to use a gradient as foreground property. Code is as below. Right now i am setting the gradient within the button tag.

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonCancel" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.68"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1.1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1.1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1.1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard_Copy1">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.68"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                        <Image x:Name="image" Source="../images/UnCategorized/Red_Oval_Button_With_Cross.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Content="CANCEL" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>

                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard_Copy1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard_Copy1}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

---

```
 <Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonCancel}" Click="btnCancel_Clicked" FontFamily="Tw Cen MT" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Width="144" Name="btnCancel"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,73.5,0,55.5">
            <Button.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#9B000000" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.OpacityMask>

        </Button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the style? If so use a setter:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonCancel" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="Foreground">
         <Setter.Value>
             <!-- LinearGradientBrush here -->
         </Setter.Value>      
     </Setter>
     <!-- ........ -->
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked. Can you please tell me how to move the foreground text to the left few pixels?

Comment: If by foreground text you just mean the text which says "CANCEL" you should set the `HorizontalAlignment` of the ContentPresenter which is responsible for it to `Left`.